# Get the information about the USB device inserted

Tags: c++, winapi, hardware-id

I've managed to check if a USB device is inserted through `WM_DEVICECHANGE`.

```
case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
{
    PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR lpdb = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lParam;

    switch(wParam)
    {
        case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
        {
            if (lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
            {
                  // Get Information about the usb device inserted
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to make sure that a right usb device was inserted by matching some kind of IDs and also I'll need to check the space available on the USB device.

One solution I can tell is to iterate through all the hardware devices until one matches with the information.

is there any another way to recognize the device upon insertion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VID and PID are sent with the DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE message. You can then look in the device drivers for more information via SetupDiGetClassDevs/SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo/SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId/SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty.

Media is not necessary available at the time of the connection. Think about a card reader, it would register drive letters but the drives won't be ready until you get a card inserted and Windows generate a [GUID_IO_MEDIA_ARRIVAL device event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363217%28VS.85%29.aspx). You can then call GetDiskFreeSpaceEx on the drive letter to get the free space.

Comment: I've got `USB\VID_0763&PID_1324\001DD0EC33B0SS6167D92815` I'm not sure what is the `001DD0EC33B0SS6167D92815` mean. thanks.